# Draw a line in a View with xml layout

Tags: android, layout

I was wondering if it's possible to draw a line anywhere on a View with an xml layout.

My app is something like this.
when one of the button is tapped, i need to draw a line from the border of the button to the the image. simply, the line that will be created will be some kind of an arrow.

Comment: Try to visit this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583015/creating-line-dividers-in-android-tab-layout-paragraphs/4583071#4583071.It may solve your problem.

Comment: I am assuming you don't want a divider sort of a line, you want something of a pointer that is drawn from the button to the image. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. i want to draw a line between the two since there are many buttons to be connected to an image.

Answer (score 0):

Create any Layouts and provide a small margin between each. Fill the margin gap with some color, this will give you a line.