# Linearlayout programmatically - How to set up a divider?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, divider

I am creating `TextViews` in `LinearLayout` programmatically and I would like to separate them with a divider (just a simple line). I have googled endlessly, what I have found is that I can use `.setDividerDrawable`, but I don't want to use external images for this.
Any tips?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### How to Add Divider to an Android Layout Programmatically

Create a `View` 1 or 2 pixels tall and width `match_parent` and set the background color to whatever color you want the divider to be.

Separate the divider from the items above and below with `margin` settings.

**Example**:

```
ImageView divider = new ImageView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = 
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
divider.setLayoutParams(lp);
divider.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but failed. How to set width to fill_parent programmatically?

Comment: Use `match_parent`, `fill_parent` was deprecated in API 8 and replaced with `match_parent`. Other than that this seems to look like a good answer.

Comment: Working flawlessly.. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple drawable in xml for the divider (example [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15128873/878126)), or use a 9-patch image which barely takes anything.

Then, use the LinearLayoutICS in order to show the divider on most of the devices. you can check out [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547897/how-to-add-dividers-to-linearlayoutics/) i've made about it.

Answer (score -1):

For linear layout you can use this attribute to set divider  android:divider="some color"
  android:showDividers="middle"